# How to keep text fields values after returning from modal in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I wonder how can I keep textfields input data when app do segue to a modal and return to the same page?

**Scenario**: I have a registration page with text fields and buttons, one of the buttons segue to a view controller that is represented as modal. Inside the modal there is a tableview, and when user click on the cell it returns data, and send user back to the registration page, but The fields get empty.

What is the best way to do it? 
the only solution I have in mind is to use NSDefaults, not sure if its a good approach.

**Clarification:**

I did the modal in storyboard, by adding a normal viewController.
Then I connected a segue between the Button and the new viewController, and selected present modally.

I specified a class for the modal "ModalVC", where it has tableview datasource and delegate functions.

then I created another segue between table cell (the one inside ModalVC) to the registration page to send the data back.

thanks

Comment: You need to give more information about what you're doing.  Presenting a modal and dismissing it wouldn't clear the values in your original view controller

Comment: kindly check the "clarification" I added above, Thanks

Comment: note I am not dismissing the modal, I am doing a segue (show) when user click on cell, and assigning data on the registration viewcontroller

Comment: callbacks and delegate will work too.

Comment: true, but a headache XD

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't dismissing the modal?  That would go back to your currently existing view controller which should still have the data filled in.  Doing another segue creates a whole new controller which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Because the modal will need to return its cell data to first view, I frankly don't know another way to do it. what do you suggest?

Comment: basically I want to show a modal that asks user to pick an item from a list, and when item is selected go back to first vc and assign new selected data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `NSUserDefaults` would work in this situation. You would have to do several things:

1. Instantiate a `NSUserDefaults` instance
2. When you first open your registration page, for each text field `title`, check if a string is stored in the defaults for that `title` (using `defaults.valueForKey("key")`)
3. If it is `nil`, then store the values inside each field by using `defaults.setValue(value, forKey: "field name")` inside the `prepareForSegue` function (in other words, right before the modal view appears)
4. If it is not `nil`, then load the values stored for each field inside defaults
5. After the registration is complete, reset the defaults by setting them to `nil`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: great thank you! :)  I was hesitating because I thought there might be some ready to use methods that handle such things automatically.

Comment: Hi mate, I went back to the class and did the defaults and eveything, the issue I face: the textfield is not putting the value? I did a print for the text fiels and it have = Optional("Optional(aaaaaa)")
, why its not placing inside text?

Comment: I put it inside viewwillappear to fill it before loading, but same issue

Comment: hahahaa, ignore my comments bro, I mistakenly checked keys but kept storing values to same field. too little sleep and too much coding I thinl XD

Answer (score 1):

For future readers who might stumble upon this question, Although Mr.Mike Schmidt answer above will definitely work, but it will be too complicated to deal with when you have too many textfields to store inside defaults, therefore too many checking , storing and reseting, which will make app logic so much tedious and nightmare to track.

**I advice you to do the following solution that I did:**

(For reference: my *Modalvc* is a *TableView* that show a list of items)

1- In storyboard Ctrl-drag from registrationvc to modalvc, and select **"present as modal"** segue

2- Instead of storing textfields values into Defaults, **store the *modalvc* values into defaults** (since it has only one value you will end up with one default) Like this:

- Instantiate defaults like this:

  ```
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  ```

  - after populating TableView with your data, Store selected tableview cell data inside default value like this:

    ```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       let cell = MyTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

       let MyValue = cell?.textLabel?.text

       defaults.setObject(MyValue, forKey: "SelectedValueKey")

        //this line will make your life easy
       self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    ```

3- **Here is the important part**, instead of doing segue from TableViewCell to registrationvc just simply do a **dismissViewControllerAnimated** => this will just dismiss the modalvc without reseting the TextFields,

Notice the line in the above code:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

4- Now back in your registrationvc check if defaults exist:

```
if defaults.valueForKey("SelectedValueKey") != nil{
        let SelectedValue = (defaults.objectForKey("SelectedValueKey") as? String)!

        print(SelectedValue)

        data.append(SelectedValue)
    }
```

5- Don't Forget to reset defaults when user click on submit button, or cancel button if you have one.

```
        defaults.removeObjectForKey("SelectedValueKey")
```

Enjoy!